# Is it possible to simplify an expression containing $\sin^2(x)$?

Tags: functions

Starting from $5-\sqrt{25-4x^2}= 10 \sin^2\frac{4.32-x}{5} $  I got here (without errors): $$ x^2= 25 \sin^2\frac{4.32-x}{5} - \frac{(10 \sin^2\frac{4.32-x}{5})^2}{4}$$

Is it possible to simplify it any further? Is it possible to find  $x=2$ without a [computer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+solve+x%5E2%3D+25+sin%5E2%28%284.31824-x%29%2F5%29+-+%28%2810+sin%5E2%28%284.31824-x%29%2F5%29%29%5E2%29%2F4)?

Comment: You have the *linearisation formulae*: $$\sin^2\theta=\frac12(1-\cos2\theta),\quad\cos^2\theta=\frac12(1+\cos2\theta)$$

Comment: You can't: this  equation involves transcendental functions. The only point in my suggestion is that is lowers the degree in sine and cosine.

Comment: Note that $x=2$ is *not* an exact solution, since $2\neq 2.00282...$. (You can see this by clicking the "more digits" button.)

Comment: Do you have an exact form?

Comment: Your question has $4.32-x$, but your WolframAlpha link has $4.31824-x$. If you're looking for the $k$ such that $10\sin^2\left(\frac{k-2}{5}\right)=2$, then $k \approx 4.31823804500403058107128115730607201014268527143060131905466544360$

Comment: That $k$ is more conveniently written using $\tan^{-1}$, since it relates to a $(1, 2, \sqrt 5)$ right triangle. $k = 2 + 5 tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$

Comment: @PM2Ring, I do not see your point, it is well represented by $5sin^-1(\sqrt{.2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would transform the initial equation this way:
$$
5\biggl(1-2 \sin^2\Bigl(\frac{4.32-x}5\Bigr)\biggr)= \sqrt{25-4x^2}\iff \cos\Bigl(\frac{8.64-2x}5\Bigr)=\sqrt{1-\Bigl(\frac{2x}5\Bigr)^2}
$$
Squaring, this implies:
\begin{align*}&\Bigl(\frac{2x}5\Bigr)^2=1-\cos^2\Bigl(\frac{8.64-2x}5\Bigr)=\sin^2\Bigl(\frac{8.64-2x}5\Bigr)\\
\iff &\begin{cases}
\dfrac{2x}5=\sin\Bigl(\dfrac{8.64-2x}5\Bigr)\\[1ex]
\dfrac{2x}5=-\sin\Bigl(\dfrac{8.64-2x}5\Bigr)
\end{cases}\\
\iff &\begin{cases}
u=\sin(1.728-u)\\[1ex]
-u=\sin(1.728-u)
\end{cases}\qquad(\text{setting}\enspace u=\frac{2x}5)
\end{align*}
These equations are easily solved by numerical methods.

*Added:*

As pointed out by @alex jordan, the second equation yields a parasitic solution, due to the squaring step.

**Extension:**

If we consider the equation: $\;5\color{red}+\sqrt{25-4x^2}= 10 \sin^2\dfrac{4.32-x}{5}$, it is transformed into 
$$5\biggl(2 \sin^2\Bigl(\frac{4.32-x}5\Bigr)-1\biggr)= \sqrt{25-4x^2}\iff -\cos\Bigl(\frac{8.64-2x}5\Bigr)=\sqrt{1-\Bigl(\frac{2x}5\Bigr)^2}$$
Squaring as before, we get the same equation as above. The difference is in the way of choosng the correct solution: the condition is now
$$\cos(1.728-u)<0\quad\text{instead of}\quad\cos(1.728-u)>0$$

Comment: +1 But note the solution to the last case is extraneous, and was introduced at the step where both sides of an equation were squared.

Comment: Oh yes! I should have mentioned it. Thank you  for pointing it!

Comment: Do you mean how to solve the final equation? I'm no specialist of numerical methods, but I suppose Newton's or fixed point methods should work.

Comment: No, there is just a change of sign in one side of the transformed equation, which disapears on squaring. The change is only in the criterion to select the correct solution. Please see my completed answer.